# Is there any function for matlab to concantenate array using condition?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, concatenation

I have this python code for concatenating 2 arrays using multiple conditions like give below

```
good_left_inds = ((nonzeroy >= win_y_low) & (nonzeroy < win_y_high) & 
    (nonzerox >= win_xleft_low) &  (nonzerox < win_xleft_high)).nonzero()
```

is there any MatLab equivalent code to work on this kind of array?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Have a look at MATLABs [`find`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function. Its documentation says

> Find indices and values of nonzero elements

It is basically the same what `numpy.nonzero` does. The logical expressions are practically identical to python code.

```matlab
% You are only interested in the indices, so you can omit the values as return parameter
[good_left_inds, ~] = find(nonzerox >= win_y_low & nonzerox < win_y_high & ...
    nonzerox >= win_xleft_low & nonzerox < win_xleft_high);
```

When comparing the results, please remember that MATLAB indexing starts at `1` and not at `0` like in python.